# How to convert 2 images to the same dimensions using Python OpenCV?

Tags: python-3.x, image, image-processing

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'resize'

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - Can't parse 'dsize'. Expected sequence length 2, got 3
> - Can't parse 'dsize'. Expected sequence length 2, got 3
>   How to convert image to the same dimensions?

```
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity
import cv2
import numpy as np

first = cv2.imread('1.png')
second = cv2.imread('3.png')

secondasnparray = np.asarray(second, dtype=int) # How to change this code properly???
second =cv2.resize(secondasnparray,first.shape)
```

## Convert images to grayscale

```
first_gray = cv2.cvtColor(first, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
second_gray = cv2.cvtColor(second, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

## Compute SSIM between two images

```
score, diff = structural_similarity(first_gray, second_gray, full=True)
print("Similarity Score: {:.3f}%".format(score * 100))
```

Comment: You are using the height, width and number channels of the first image, but you should only use the first two, i.e. `second =cv2.resize(secondasnparray,first.shape[:2])`

Comment: Why are you using np.asarray when cv2.imread already creates a dumpy array for second?

Comment: If you want to convert from `uint8` to `int`, you can use `intArray = uint8Array.astype(np.int)`

Comment: Have tried your idea: from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity
import cv2
import numpy as np

first = cv2.imread('1.png')
second = cv2.imread('3.png')


#second =cv2.resize(second,first.shape[:2]) 

secondresized =cv2.resize(second,first.shape[:2]) 
# Convert images to grayscale
first_gray = cv2.cvtColor(first, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
second_gray = cv2.cvtColor(secondresized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) Traceback (most 
    raise ValueError('Input images must have the same dim.... ADVISE another IDEA, thank you

Answer (score 1):

the following code solves the problem:

```
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity
import cv2
import numpy as np

first = cv2.imread('1.png')
second = cv2.imread('3.png')


firstresized =  cv2.resize(second,first.shape[:2]) # making images of the same dimensions
secondresized = cv2.resize(first,first.shape[:2])
```